Understand Putty ppkv3 flow
I asked a question yesterday about how the ppk file is generated. I got the answer but how can I derive the aes key and the IV? For example by using CyberChef?
I have the passphrase and the salt, how can I generate the keys so I can aes-decrypt the encrypted private key?

I've tried to find out the details myself, but it seems to require source code analysis or something similar :/
